# Project Euler #6 Python

Tags: python, project

The question I'm trying to solve is here: https://projecteuler.net/problem=6

I tried this but all that was printed were two zeroes:

```
sumsquare = 0
ssum = 0
def sumsquaredif(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        num = i ** 2
        num += sumsquare
        i += ssum
    squaresum = ssum**2
    print (squaresum)
    print (sumsquare)
    return
sumsquaredif(10)
```

And then of course I'd have to add the code to subtract sumsquare from squaresum and print that. But this preliminary code isn't working. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help. I'm still a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have the line `i += ssum`?

Comment: you assign `ssum = 0` and never change that or add anything to it.

Comment: Please include the question in your question (!), not just a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `+=` assignments are the wrong way! `num += sumsquare` is adding the sum to the current number, not the other way around, and similar for `ssum`. Also, the sum variables should be declared inside of the function.

```
def sumsquaredif(n):
    sumsquare = 0  # inside function
    ssum = 0       # inside function
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        num = i ** 2
        sumsquare += num  # inversed
        ssum += i         # inversed
    squaresum = ssum**2
```

Also, you could make that code much shorter by using list comprehensions:

```
sumsquare = sum(n for n in range(1, n+1))**2
squaresum = sum(n**2 for n in range(1, n+1))
```